# cypher query that concatenates a key/property of a string with a key/property of an array

Tags: json, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am trying to build a cypher query that I plan to use as a json response to a http request. I’d like to have two keys in the json object: one key/property of type string and another key/property of type array that looks like this:

```
> {
>     "id"                                : "9989898676876_all",
>     "inventory"                         : [
>         {
>             "id"                        : "a_aaa",
>             "isFavorite"                : false
>         }, {
>             "id"                        : "b_bbb",
>             "isFavorite"                : false
>         }, {    
>             "id"                        : "c_ccc",
>             "isFavorite"                : false
>         }, {
>             "id"                        : "d_ddd",
>             "isFavorite"                : false
>         }
>     ] }
```

I tried with this cypher query but cam up with errors:

```
MATCH n 
WHERE n.id='9989898676876'
RETURN n.id + '_all' AS `id`
UNION
MATCH n-[inventory:ALL_]->leaf
WHERE n.id='9989898676876'
RETURN (leaf.id AS `id`, inventory.isFavorite AS `isFavorite`) AS `inventory`
```

Can someone please provide a fiddle example of a cypher response that concatenates a key/property of a string with a key/property of an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can get the results, with the inventory ordered by ascending `leaf.id`:

```
MATCH n-[inventory:ALL_]->leaf
WHERE n.id='9989898676876'
WITH *
ORDER BY leaf.id
RETURN (n.id + '_all') AS id, COLLECT({ id: leaf.id, isFavorite: inventory.isFavorite }) AS inventory;
```

Comment: How would you Order By the array inside the COLLECT ?

Comment: you have to order by upfront with a `WITH` and then collect afterwards

Comment: I have updated my answer to order the inventory by `leaf.id`.